# Should custom ASP.NET Core options implement IOptions<>?

Tags: asp.net-core

When browsing the official documenation on ASP.NET Core configuration, we can find the following sample. This is also dominant in other samples out there.

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public MyOptions()
    {
        // Set default value.
        Option1 = "value1_from_ctor";
    }
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public int Option2 { get; set; } = 5;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration

I was browsing the ASP.NET Core Caching repo and noticed a slight difference in how the Microsoft team does it.

```
public class MemoryCacheOptions : IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions>
{
    // removed stuff

    MemoryCacheOptions IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions>.Value
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCacheOptions.cs

What is the benefit of implementing IOptions<>? What type of 'magic' does it give us?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to implement the interface. As far as I know, it does not provide any value. Most of the code in the class is rather old (2-3 years) so it might just be some leftovers from an earlier options implementation. In fact, my guess it that it can be removed safely.

Answer (score 0):

Posted the question on the ASP.NET Core github and got an answer from one of the devs. By implementing IOptions<>, you can more easily use it in unit tests without having the Options infrastructure in place.

Comment: After digging the GitHub repo, I found your post https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/190. Post here because I think it may help.